# QT load .dll not calling resolve

Tags: c++, qt, dll

For Some reason I can load my .dll fine into my application but when i call the resolve function it keeps saying unable to load function.

```
typedef void (*SetKey_func)(const char *, const char *, const char *, const char *);

Crypt::Crypt(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
}

Crypt::~Crypt()
{

}

void Crypt::LoadCrypt()
    {

        QString file = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/RockBase.dll";

        library.setFileName(file);
        library.load();

        if( !library.isLoaded() )
        {
            //file not loaded
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            // file loaded
        }
    }
```

Then my function decsetkey just sets the key inside the .dll

```
void Crypt::DecSetKey()
{

    quint8 decKey1[] = { 0x7D, 0x44, 0x01, 0x00, 0x83, 0xEC, 0x24, 0x83, 0x25, 0xB8, 0x8C, 0x4A, 0x0D, 0x56, 0x8B, 0x75 };
    quint8 decKey2[] = { 0x1C, 0x8D, 0x1C, 0x57, 0x50, 0xCE, 0xE8, 0x6F, 0x85, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0x8B };
    quint8 decKey3[] = { 0x76, 0x0C, 0x50, 0x45, 0x14, 0x83, 0x65, 0xFC, 0x56, 0x50, 0x7D, 0xD1, 0x74, 0x03, 0xB8, 0x43 };
    quint8 decKey4[] = { 0x8B, 0x47, 0xDD, 0x6A, 0xE8, 0x14, 0x83, 0xC4, 0xBC, 0xF3, 0x7F, 0x75 };

    SetKey_func s_d_func = (SetKey_func)library.resolve( "?SetKey@CCrypto@RockBase@@QAEXPBD000@Z" );
    if( s_d_func )
    {
        //"Successful loading of Decrypt CCrypto::SetKey function."));
        s_d_func( 0, (const char*)decKey1, 0, 0 );
        s_d_func((const char*)decKey2, 0, 0, 0);
        s_d_func(0, (const char*)decKey3, 0, 0);
        s_d_func((const char*)decKey4, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        //Unable to load Decrypt CCrypto::SetKey function."));
    }
}
```

i call in another class the function

```
void patch::readdata()
{
        Crypt *cryptinstance = new Crypt(this);
        cryptinstance->DecSetKey();
}
```

I think the pointer is getting destroyed after i acecss it. Any help would be helpfull thanks for your time.

Comment: Do a `dumpbin /exports Rockbase.dll`.  Are you sure you have the name mangled function signature correct?  Also, you probably really want to be exporting a flat "extern C" function instead of a C++ function.

Comment: ya the names are mangled i have no access to the lib or header file just the .dll any suggestions

Comment: Share the DLL out and I can likely tell you what's wrong....

Comment: /*
visual studio c++ 6.0 (.dll)
; Exported entry 119. ?SetKey@CRockCrypto@RockBase@@QAEXPBD000@Z
 
 
; Attributes: bp-based frame
 
; void __thiscall RockBase::CRockCrypto::SetKey(RockBase::CRockCrypto *this, const char *, const char *, const char *, const char *)
public ?SetKey@CRockCrypto@RockBase@@QAEXPBD000@Z
?SetKey@CRockCrypto@RockBase@@QAEXPBD000@Z proc near
 
 
*/      this should be:             typedef void (*SetKey_func)(void* thisPtr,const char *, const char *, const char *, const char *);  then i would  be getting the class instance ptr. But not sure how to do that.

Comment: Literally,  I meant,  send me a copy of the DLL.

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=07118560259434205572 Here is the .dll you requested

Answer (score 0):

Do a `dumpbin /exports RockBaseML.dll` from the command line. You'll see that there is no such exported function as `?SetKey@CCrypto@RockBase@@QAEXPBD000@Z` as your code attempts to search for.  The closest I found was this set:

```
C:\Users\jselbie\Downloads>dumpbin /exports RockBaseML.dll | findstr /i SetKey
    116   73 00004DCF ?SetKey@CAesCrypto@RockBase@@UAEXPBD@Z
    117   74 00004F3D ?SetKey@CDesCrypto@RockBase@@UAEXPBD@Z
    118   75 00005051 ?SetKey@CRcCrypto@RockBase@@UAEXPBD@Z
    119   76 0000525E ?SetKey@CRockCrypto@RockBase@@QAEXPBD000@Z
    120   77 000054F2 ?SetKey@CStrmCrypto@RockBase@@UAEXPBD@Z
```

Comment: ?SetKey@CRockCrypto@RockBase@@QAEXPBD000@Z  is what i used sorry for the typo in the source..

Comment: Could you explain why my .dll is not working correctly? I load the dll grab the proccess pass a fucntion with arguments and it just crashes any ideas why?

Comment: Sorry. The DLL had dependencies to other DLLs thatI didn't have. I don't have enough to go on.  I tried.

Comment: sorry should of posted the other. Here try this and see what you can come up with thankyou for your help.. http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=85382418382697538359